# Launch multiple processes of COM-Object for a multiuser capable Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, com

I'm more or less new to .NET development as well as to techniques like WCF and COM(+). I think I'm little bit informed about these topics, even though I just skim over some of those.

Problem:
I want to develop a multi-client capable Webservice which should have the ability to make a "session"-based usage of an existing COM-Object. (The COM-Object already exists and couldn't be changed)

The COM-Object (Dll) itself loads two (unmanaged) Dlls. And now here comes the tricky part:

If I create ONE instance of the COM-Object in a sample C# client (console app), everything works fine at that point, because the Instance runs in process. (Those unmanaged Dlls just loaded once each process). So if I'm going to create another instance of the COM-Object in the same process, the app crashes. This is an expecting behavior because those Dlls are not thread save.

A first conclusion was that I have to create just ONE COM-Instance each (isolated) process!

But what about create multiple instances of the COM-Object in as Webapp which bases on user-sessions?

What I have tried already:
1. I created a new Appdomain for each COM-instance.

-> **Dont work**, because unmanaged Code don't know about Appdomains.

I made a COM+ library from the COM-Object and I created a WCF service with the utility (ComSvcConfig) and hosted it finally in IIS (WAS).

-> **Don't work**, because it runs in the same process (worker-processes).

I created a first WCF-Service of the COM-Object and created the appropriate service-operations for each COM-Function.
I created a second WCF-Service that just generates a new instance of the first Selfhosting WCF-Service. The second WCF-Service starts and returns an unique URL of the first service in order that each client have its own and  Selfhosted service in a separated process.

-> **Works!** But it seems very complicated and it isn't probably a good programming style IMO.

Conclusion:

May I haven't considered several aspects to make a suitable solution (due to lack of knowledge). So may there are other (better) ways to solve the problem?

Do you have some advices and tips to solve the problem more conveniently?

Thanks in advance!